# Is there anywhere in Aus/NZ that sells MiniBrew HDPE?

Tags: fermentation, beer, equipment, conical-fermenter

Pretty much, the title. I've done a few searches and turn up the Malt Mechanics products, but no [MiniBrew](https://www.minibrew.com). If you have Minibrew equipment and you live in Aus/NZ, where do you get your parts from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look like there is. Ordered online from US! Emailed the guys and they were very helpful.